# Filter HTML table

Tags: html, vbscript, filter

I am trying to filter a table on my website using VBScript. A user will use a search term to narrow results. If a row has a column that contains the search term, the row is not hidden. It's been a while since I've used it, and I can't get it working. By "not working" I mean all rows in the table still appear.

```html
<html>

<script language="VBScript">
Sub filterResults()
  Dim searchBox
  Set searchBox = Document.forms("searchBoxID")

  For Each subInstance In document.GetElementsByTagName("tr")
    If Not subInstance.OuterHTML.Contains(searchBox.filterTXT.Value) Then
      subInstance.style = "display:none"
    End If
  Next
End Sub
</script>

<form id="searchBoxID" 
  onsubmit="filterResults(); return false;" language="jscript">

Filter results: 
<input name="filterTXT" type="text" size="2">
<input name="Submit" type="Submit" value="Submit">

<table border=1>
  <th>Row One</th><th>Row Two</th><th>Row Three</th>
  <tr>
    <td>Stuff</td><td>Things</td><td>Items</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Possessions</td><td>Objects</td><td>Things</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no `Contains` method in VBScript. Use the [InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function:

```
For Each subInstance In document.GetElementsByTagName("tr")
    If InStr(subInstance.OuterHTML, searchBox.filterTXT.Value) = 0 Then
        subInstance.style = "display:none"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Ah, that would definitely help. According to FireFox, it says my subroutine is not defined...

Comment: Firefox doesn't support VBScript. Internet Explorer is the only browser that supports VBScript, and in IE11, that's only in compatibility view (or whatever it's called now).

Comment: Well guess I won't be using VBScript for my purposes. Thanks.